# Microsoft Access 2010 Access SOAP web service

Tags: ms-access-2010

Has any body tried accessing SOAP Web Service In Microsoft Access?

I tried to used information from the following link to access the Web Service and received this Error: The Microsoft Access database engine encountered an error while connecting to Data Services: 'The Model contains Lob System [External System] of Type 'WebService' which is not supported.'

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-web-service-data-connection-HA010356867.aspx#BM3

In the screen they show Dialog to Create Link to Web Service which I am not able to find in MS Access 2010. I see a similar screen in Create Link to Data Services and I used that to access the Web Service that gave me error specified above.

Any idea on the error, Do I have to download any add-in to see 'Create Link to Web Service'?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Office 2003 Web Services toolkit with a great level of success

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2224